# How to use Jackson library annotations to avoid infinite recursion and still get some properties at the same time?

Tags: spring, jackson, infinite-loop, one-to-one

I have two simple classes : `Student` and `Certificate`, related by a bidirectionnal @OneToOne relationship.
My goal is to retrieve the certificate from the student, which works fine using @OneToOne and @JsonIgnore, but also get some student nested informations from the certificate nested into the student.

My Java classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int studentId;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "mean")
    private double mean;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="student" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
    private Certificate certificate;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "certificate")    
public class Certificate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int certificateId;

    @Column(name = "aknowledgment")
    private String aknowledgment;

    @OneToOne() 
@JoinColumn(name="student_id", nullable= false)   
@JsonBackReference
    private Student student;

}
```

The issue I am facing here is I want to get student's id from the certificate injected in the student entity, something like this :

```
{
        studentId: 0,
        name: 'John',
        age: 19,
        certificate : {
            certificateId: 0,
            aknowledgment : 'granted to',
            student : {
                studentId: 0
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I avoid infinite recursion but getting this student's id in the certificate object ?
Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

you could archieve it by follow

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "certificate")    
public class Certificate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int certificateId;

    @Column(name = "aknowledgment")
    private String aknowledgment;

    @OneToOne() 
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id", nullable= false)   
    @JsonIncludeProperties({ "studentId" })
// @JsonBackReference
    private Student student;

}
```

replace the @JsonBackReference with the @JsonIncludeProperties({ "studentId" }). the process just serialize the studentId, so it does not trigger recursion. The @JsonBackReference must be remove, otherwise the student field that in the Certificate class will the detect, so the final resutl will not have such field.